# Let $|z_1| = |z_2| = 1$. Prove that $\frac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2}$ is an imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers

Could someone help me:

1. prove that $\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2}$ is an imaginary number
2. prove that $\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}$ is a real number.

Comment: Use $\overline{z_1}=z_1^{-1}$ etc.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than votes to close and downvotes if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I do not see why you think I should get downvotes. I am just stuck and do not know how to start solving the problem.

Comment: You have gotten a downvote (not mine) because the expectation here when you ask a question is that you will show at least a little bit of effort of your own. "Not knowing how to start" isn't quite enough. You could tell us that you know how to tell whether a complex number is real or imaginary. You could show us some examples you computed to check special cases. Please do that kind of work if you have more questions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

With $2{\bf Re}w=w+\bar{w}$ we have
$$2{\bf Re}\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2} = \dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2}+\overline{\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2}} = \dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2} + \dfrac{\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2}}{1-\overline{z_1}\overline{z_2}} = \dfrac{0}{|1-z_1z_2|^2}=0.$$
Then $\dfrac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2}$ is imaginary. (Note that $z_1\bar{z_1}=z_2\bar{z_2}=1$).

The second is similar.

Comment: Hey at the last step how did you get $0$ on the numerator ? Did you do common denominator and simplify ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am sorry, in class we never used such a thing as 2Re.

Comment: @EliasAbunuwara $\bf Re$ just refers to the real part : $$\bf Re(a+ib) = a$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2}= \frac{(z_1+z_2)(1-\bar z_1\bar z_2)}{(1-z_1z_2)(1-\bar z_1\bar z_2)}= \frac{(z_1-\bar z_1)+(z_2-\bar z_2)}{(1-z_1z_2)(1-\bar z_1\bar z_2)},$$ which is pure imaginary.

Similarly, $$\frac{z_1+z_2}{1+z_1z_2}= \frac{(z_1+z_2)(1+\bar z_1\bar z_2)}{(1+z_1z_2)(1+\bar z_1\bar z_2)}= \frac{(z_1+\bar z_1)+(z_2+\bar z_2)}{(1+z_1z_2)(1+\bar z_1\bar z_2)},$$

which is real.

Answer (score 1):

A number is real if and only if it equals its conjugate: the conjugate of the second number is
$$
\frac{\overline{z_1+z_2}}{\;\vphantom{\Big|}\overline{1+z_1z_2}\;}=
\frac{\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_1}}{1+\overline{z_1}\overline{z_2}}=
\frac{\dfrac{1}{z_1}+\dfrac{1}{z_2}}{1+\dfrac{1}{z_1}\dfrac{1}{z_2}}
$$
because $|z|=1$ if and only if $\bar{z}=z^{-1}$.

Can you do similarly for the first number? A number $z$ is purely imaginary if and only if $\bar{z}=-z$.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $z_1 = e^{i\phi}, z_2 = e^{i\psi}$

$$
\frac{ e^{i\phi}+e^{i\psi}}{1- e^{i\phi} e^{i\psi}} = i \cos \left(\frac{\phi-\psi}{2}\right) \csc \left(\frac{\phi+\psi}{2}\right)
$$